# Google Play has added support for testing in-app subscription purposes?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, subscriptions

Up until now it was my understanding that Google Play only supported testing in-app purchases of products (consumables and non-consumables), however today when I went to purchase one of my app's subscriptions the Google Play popup window showed a message to the effect "this is a test purchase and will be auto renewed every day" (it's actually set to be a monthly subscription).

I checked the Google docs [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html) and it still explicitly says "http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html". I'm wondering if Google has unofficially released support for testing subscriptions but just haven't publicly announced it yet.

I don't recall seeing such a message when we tested the subscriptions (by actually paying money and then refunding ourselves). Has anybody else noticed this change?

Answer (score 1):

If you have published your app under Alpha or Beta Testing,Google Play will provide support for IAB testing.Under the app details you can check "Licence Testing" checkbox for your application and provide some of email address which are licensed to test your application.When you will click on Purchase if google account is one the the licensed testing account then it will show this is test order and your money will not get deducted and you can test in app purchase.

check this [Setting Up Test Accounts for In-App Billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-testing-setup)

Hope it will help.

Comment: Hi, I'm aware of this but it was my understanding that even this didn't support testing for subscriptions but it seems they do now.